# <html:radio> Check radio button default in struts html tag

Tags: struts, struts-1

How to set radio button checked by default in struts html tag ?

```
<html:radio name="RegisterForm" property="Group"  value="<%=Contant.Male%>"/><label>Male</label><BR>
<html:radio name="RegisterForm" property="Group" value="<%=Contant.Female%>"/><label>Female</label>
```

Here, i have to set Male as default one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make sue that your controller sets the corresponding property in the form before dispatching to the view:

```
form.setGroup(Constant.Male);
```