# How to set an <html:radio> checked by default in Struts 1.1

Tags: jsp, struts, custom-tags

I'm trying to find out how to make a radio button checked by default when using jsp and struts 1.1 with custom tag.

When i write my code this way :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
....................................................................  
<html:radio property="operazione" value="addizione" checked="checked">Addizione</html:radio>  
<br />
```

eclipse say :

> Undefined attribute name "checked"

and when i try to run this code on my server Tomcat this is what i get:

> Attribute checked invalid for tag radio according to TLD

I've read [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237731/htmlradio-check-radio-button-default-in-struts-html-tag) but it involves JavaScript...
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't involves javascript. All you need to do is set the property value in the respective action form. While loading the page, set the `actionForm.property=value` in the action class. If you required in javascript,

```
(function() {
   // Set the value on loading the page
   document.getElementByID("elementID").value=1;
})();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: now i get it !
simply when the form is submitted, the action class have to test if the property associated with the radio is null or not; if null the action have to set the value to the default one...

Comment: so there is no attribute for <html:radio ... /> to set one radio button selected :/